# regex lookarounds, combining lookahead and lookbehind

Tags: regex

I am trying to grab the words after "Expertise" and before "Most" in the following string:

```
"Top Skills & Expertise   Project Management  Cooking  Childcare  Tutoring       Most Recommended"
```

Based on examples, I think that I should be using this:

```
(?<=Top Skills & Expertise).*(Most Recommended?=)
```

But that doesn't seem to work, so I use this:

```
(?<=)Top Skills & Expertise.*Most Recommended(?=)
```

Of course, in the second case, the "Top Skills & Expertise" and the "Most Recommended" are consumed and returned, which I don't want.

I"m sure there is just something simple that I'm missing here.  Any guidance for a regex newbie will be appreciated!!

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You got lookahead part wrong:

```
(?<=Top Skills & Expertise).*(?=Most Recommended)
```

Comment: Great, I knew I had to have something wrong here that was straightforward.  I found that the expression as you have it above didn't quite work, though.  I needed to do (?<=Top Skills & Expertise)\s.*(?=Most Recommended).  Not sure why, though.